# Set focus to an element

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an `async` HTTP call and want to set a focus to an error element in a template if the `async` call results in an error.

- One way can be to inject the `ElementRef` and then use jQuery to access element and call `focus()` method on it.

```js
class MyComponent {
   
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

    doAsync() {
        // do something async

        $(this.element.nativeElement).find('.error').focus();
    }
}
```

- Another way may be to create a directive, that binds to a property on model and calls `focus()` method on a host element.

How good is to include/use JQuery in angular 2?

Also, I believe the way Angular is meant to work (MV*) is to '**modify model to which view reacts**'. So, which one is correct way to do it?

Comment: What type of element are you trying to focus on?

Comment: @MichaelSolati Any error prompt, say a bootstrap alert `<div class="alert alert-danger>{{errorPrompt}}</div>`

Comment: Since you're targeting a class and because the class can be used in multiple places, it would be pretty dirty to target every single element using that class. Mind you you can do a conditional directive to show the class if a condition is true

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's try this in your focus component

```
 import --> AfterViewInit

 export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('err') vc: any;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.vc.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

use this component html

```
<div #err class="alert alert-danger>{{errorPrompt}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what kind of element '.error' is, but you could try something like this:

```
class MyComponent {

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    doAsync() {
        // do something async

        setTimeout(() => {
            const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('.error');
            if (element) {
                element.focus();
            }
        }, 200);
    }

}
```

I've found setTimeout is sometimes necessary if the element is nested in an *ngIf. Although not the cleanest solution, it's at least better than including jquery. You could also define your own directive for an autofocus reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the result of your async function set a property on the component to show or hide the error message.

```
class MyComponent {

    hasErrors = false;
    errorPrompt = ""; 

    constructor() {}

    doAsync() {
        // do something async
        this.hasErrors = true;
        this.errorPrompt = "Fix the errors.";
    }
}
```

In the mark up:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="hasErrors">{{errorPrompt}}</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use angular directive of class:

```
<component1 [ngClass]="{focusClass: setFocus() }"></component1>
```

if setFocus() return true active the class that put focus in the tag

Comment: What is focusClass?

Comment: focusClass is a css class where you define the focus, not use jquery

Comment: But isn't the point to actually focus on the element, not manipulating the UI using some CSS classes?